# UIColor - changing colour of object

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, uicolor

I want to change the colour of an object that is generated repeatedly after my hero passes it while running in order to make it look like hero is collecting coins. To do so, I wrote "coinGS.coin.color = UIColor.clearColor()" in "override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)" method in the GameScene. I implemented my coin and coin generation in separate files and it gives me the error Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. Can someone please help me with how should I change it to make it work. Here is my coin implementation and gamescene implementation. I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

```
import Foundation

import SpriteKit

class AKCoin: SKSpriteNode {

let Coin_Width: CGFloat = 10.0
let Coin_Height: CGFloat = 10.0
let Coin_Color = UIColor.yellowColor()
var coin: SKSpriteNode!

init(){

    let size = CGSizeMake(Coin_Width, Coin_Height)
    super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.clearColor() , size: size)

    //physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: size)
    //physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    loadAppearance()
    coinStartMoving()


}

func loadAppearance(){

    let coin = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellowColor(), size: CGSizeMake(Coin_Width,Coin_Height))
    coin.position = CGPointMake(0, 2)
    addChild(coin)

 }
}
```

---

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var movingGround: AKMovingGround!
var hero: AKHero!
var cloudGenerator: AKCloudGenerator!
var obstacleGenerator: AKObstacleGenerator!
var coinGenerator: AKCoinGenerator!
var coinGS: AKCoin!
var isStarted = false
var isGameOver = false

var currentLevel = 0

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 159.0/255.0, green: 201.0/255.0 , blue: 244.0/255.0 , alpha: 1.0)
  }


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
if coinGenerator.coinTracker.count > 0{

        let coin = coinGenerator.coinTracker[0] as AKCoin
        let coinLocation = coinGenerator.convertPoint(coin.position, toNode: self)

        if  coinLocation.x < hero.position.x {

            coinGS.coin.color = UIColor.clearColor()

            coinGenerator.coinTracker.removeAtIndex(0)
            let CoinsLabel = childNodeWithName("CoinsLabel") as! AKCoinsLabel
                CoinsLabel.increment()
                }  
         }
      }
```

Comment: Where you initialise `coinGS`?

Comment: I wrote this function in GameScene;    
         func addcoinC(){     
        coinGS = AKCoin()
        coinGS.position = view!.center
        addChild(coinGS)
    }

Comment: It looks like `coinGS` is not initialised when you work with it. Have you tried to check in debugger is it initialised?